# Allow child panel to popup outside of parent control/form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, panel

We have a custom timeline-esque control we're creating in C#/WinForms. In it, we have a bunch of keyframes that, when clicked, popup a properties dialog with specific and dynamic controls based on the type of keyframe it is.

This box is currently drawn within the timeline's clip rectangle, so if it's bigger than the available space only shows part of the panel. I wouldn't mind allowing this panel to break out of the parent's clip rectangle, and even overhang outside of the form itself.

The only problem is I don't know where to begin! Thanks!

Comment: You are not allowed to color outside of the lines in Windows.  What you paint is always clipped by the window's client area.  Another top-level window is required.  A Form, not a Control.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for commenting (and not for the first time either, you're incredible!). I would be content with just being able to draw it outside of the control, and keep it within the form, it would help me eek out that much more space. Thanks!

Comment: A panel is also a window so has the same restriction.  At least you can make it larger and still see it.  Maybe you ought to consider popping up a form when the control is double-clicked, something like that.  A zoom feature operated by the mouse wheel is the common solution for a timeline.